# What is recommended color recognition sensor RGB for different cases?

Tags: sensors

What is recommended color recognition sensor in the following two cases:

- To determine the color of the floor while the robot is moving (multi-color line follower).
- To determine the color of an object in distance 10cm at least.

For both cases above, I am looking for a sensor so that I can get values like (R: 252 , G: 217 , B: 0) not only red, green or blue as an result, and no problem with small errors.

Comment: Why analog? Just curious ...

Comment: @LookAlterno e.g. (R: 252 , G: 217 , B: 0)

Comment: That's looks digital to me. Analog means you are reading a voltage at an input pin. Please, clarify editing your question.

Comment: Why analog? Digital ones are far more common and some give more sensitivity and accuracy than the Arduino ADC can give.

Comment: @LookAlterno How many pins do you need to read this three values as digital output? 3 * log2(256) pins !!

Comment: @Majenko Could you explain to me how to get values like (R: 252, G: 217, B: 0) using few number of pins, please? (I'm really a newbie).

Comment: Take DHT11, a temp/humidity sensor. It's digital and it uses only one pin for data. Data is serially transmited, one bit at time.

Comment: Question edited, waiting for your answers, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conceptual error. You don't need *n* wires to transmite *n* bits of information. If you use a *serial protocol*, one wire or two is enough to transmit information of any size: you just send one bit after another.

Just think: you are downloading sketchs in your Arduino thru a cable with only 4 wires ...

Most sensors (and modules) for Arduino use I2C or SPI to transmit commands/information in digital format. You can learn a lot in this [tutorial](http://www.deviceplus.com/how-tos/arduino-guide/arduino-communication-protocols-tutorial/) that covers I2C, SPI and USB.

A quick search on Aliexpress show me this APDS-9960 sensor

[image: APDS-9960 sensor]

The sensor provide ambient light and color measurement, proximity detection and non-contact gesture detection. The APDS-9960 has built in UV and IR blocking filters, four separate diodes sensitive to different directions, and an I2C compatible interface.

Pins: VL (optional power to IR LED), GND (Ground), VCC (power to APDS-9960 sensor), SDA (I2C data), SCL (I2C clock), and INT (interrupt). Each APDS-9960 also has a detection range of 4 to 8 inches (10 to 20 cm).

It works with 3.3V.

Comment: Sorry for the conceptual error, thanks a lot.